# Function to extract elements from a list column into a new column using purrr:::map

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rlang

I want to extract elements from a list column and store them as a new column. I can do this outside of a function, but I can't get this to work within a function.

In the example code below, I want the line `mutate(!!F_name := map(!!sum_name, ~.$statistic[[1]]))` to extract the test statistic from the model summary column and store it in a new column. This gives an Evaluation error `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.

```
aov_f1 <- function(df) {aov(value~ carb, data = df)}
aov_f2 <- function(df) {aov(value~ carb + gear, data = df)}

aov_sum_plus <- function(df, mod) {
  mod <- enquo(mod)
  sum_name <- paste0(quo_name(mod), "_sum")
  F_name <-paste0(quo_name(mod), "_F")

  df <- df %>%
    mutate(!!sum_name := map(!! mod, broom::tidy)) %>%
    mutate(!!F_name := map(!!sum_name, ~.$statistic[[1]]))

  df
}

mtcars_n <- gather(mtcars, obs, value, mpg:qsec) %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(aov1 = map(data, aov_f1)) %>%
  mutate(aov2 = map(data, aov_f2)) %>%
  aov_sum_plus(aov1) %>%
  aov_sum_plus(aov2)
```

The equivalent code below gives the desired result.

```
aov_f1 <- function(df) {aov(value~ carb, data = df)}
aov_f2 <- function(df) {aov(value~ carb + gear, data = df)}

mtcars_n <- gather(mtcars, obs, value, mpg:qsec) %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(aov1 = map(data, aov_f1)) %>%
  mutate(aov2 = map(data, aov_f2)) %>%
  mutate(aov1_sum = map(aov1, broom::tidy)) %>%
  mutate(aov2_sum = map(aov2, broom::tidy)) %>%
  mutate(aov1_sum_f = map_dbl(aov1_sum, ~.$statistic[[1]])) %>%
  mutate(aov1_sum_p = map_dbl(aov1_sum, ~.$p.value[[1]])) %>%
  mutate(aov2_sum_f = map_dbl(aov2_sum, ~.$statistic[[1]])) %>%
  mutate(aov2_sum_p = map_dbl(aov2_sum, ~.$p.value[[1]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unquoting `sum_name` into a string. This won't work in `map`. You can check this by running:

```
debugfun <- function(df, mod) {
  mod <- enquo(mod)
  sum_name <- paste0(quo_name(mod), "_sum")
  F_name <-paste0(quo_name(mod), "_F")

  quo(df <- df %>%
    mutate(!!sum_name := map(!! mod, broom::tidy),
           !!F_name := map(!!sum_name, ~.$statistic[[1]])
    )
  )
}

gather(mtcars, obs, value, mpg:qsec) %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(aov1 = map(data, aov_f1)) %>%
  debugfun(aov1)
```

Giving:

> ```
> <quosure>
>   expr: ^df <- df %>% mutate("aov1_sum" := map(^aov1, broom::tidy), "aov1_F" := map("aov1_sum", ~.$statistic[[1]]))
>   env:  0000015EF2AD5C88
> ```

This is a need trick! Using `quo` on your entire expression will translate it for you. Looking at the second `map` we see the problem with the strings.

You need to create a symbol (or name) from your strings. You can add them to your `paste0` lines:

```
aov_sum_plus <- function(df, mod) {
  mod <- enquo(mod)
  sum_name <- sym(paste0(quo_name(mod), "_sum"))
  F_name   <- sym(paste0(quo_name(mod), "_F"))

  mutate(
    df,
    !!sum_name := map(!! mod, broom::tidy),
    !!F_name := map_dbl(!!sum_name, ~.$statistic[[1]])
  )
}

gather(mtcars, obs, value, mpg:qsec) %>%
  group_by(obs) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(aov1 = map(data, aov_f1)) %>%
  aov_sum_plus(aov1)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
>   obs   data              aov1      aov1_sum         aov1_F
>   <chr> <list>            <list>    <list>            <dbl>
> 1 mpg   <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]> 13.1  
> 2 cyl   <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]> 11.5  
> 3 disp  <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]>  5.55 
> 4 hp    <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]> 38.5  
> 5 drat  <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]>  0.249
> 6 wt    <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]>  6.71 
> 7 qsec  <tibble [32 x 5]> <S3: aov> <tibble [2 x 6]> 22.7
> ```